# Ask Google Assistant to read my notifications

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to read Android notifications through Google Assistant?

Use case:
"Ok Google, read my notifications"
Google Assistant:
"You have one unread messages from.."

Answer (score 0):

I just asked and it said "I can't read your notifications yet."

I think the answer is no.

Comment: Funny :) I have not thought about asking to it. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Technically, you could build an Android app which reads notifications and stores them on your server. Then you write an Actions on Google app to read from your server, ie. "OK Google, talk to my notifications". But that may be a lot of additional work on your part and perhaps not a good user experience.